# PBS_MARQUEE Progressbar WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, progress-bar

I'm trying to get a progress bar of the type PBS_MARQUEE working.
I can create the progress bar, but i just can't manage it to make it moving.

If found this, but i don't understand clearly what i have to do:

"Turns out since i had the progress bar as a resource instead of using the CreateWindowEx(..) i had to use SetWindowLongPtr(..) to set the PBS_MARQUEE style for this control..."

I create the progressbar that way:

```
   hwndPB = CreateWindowEx(0, PROGRESS_CLASS,
                            (LPSTR)NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | PBS_MARQUEE ,
                            rcClient.left,
                            rcClient.bottom - cyVScroll,
                            rcClient.right, cyVScroll,
                            hwnd, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Then i try to make it working:

```
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwndPB,GWL_STYLE,PBS_MARQUEE);
    SendMessage(hwndPB,(UINT) PBM_SETMARQUEE,(WPARAM) 1,(LPARAM)NULL );
```

Thx & regards

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are obliterating the window style.  The error is the line:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwndPB,GWL_STYLE,PBS_MARQUEE);
```

This sets the `PBS_MARQUEE` style flag, but removes all other flags, most definitely not what you intend.

Instead you should use bitwise OR like so:

```
LONG_PTR style = GetWindowLongPtr(wndPB, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLongPtr(hwndPB, GWL_STYLE, style | PBS_MARQUEE);
```

I'm know next to nothing about C++ type rules so there will probably be wrinkles with this code, but I'm sure that this is your problem!

In fact, since you set the window style in the call to `CreateWindowEx()` I don't see why you need to modify it at all.

---

One final hunch at why your marquee progress bar is not working. Did you include a manifest for common controls v6? The marquee style is only supported in common controls v6 and up.

You can do this most simply by including the following in, for example, stdafx.h:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

I tested this with the following code added to the blank Win32 project in Visual Studio:

```
HWND hwndPB = CreateWindowEx(
    0, PROGRESS_CLASS, (LPCWSTR)NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | PBS_MARQUEE,
    0, 0, 400, 100,
    hWnd, (HMENU) 0, hInst, NULL
);
SendMessage(hwndPB,(UINT) PBM_SETMARQUEE,(WPARAM) 1,(LPARAM)NULL);
ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);
```

I needed to add the manifest pragma to get v6 comctl32 and without the pragma there was no marquee.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. I don't really want to modify it, but i don't know how to make the progress bar, declared as PBS_MARQUEE, moving... In my view it should work with the CreateWindowEx() and the  SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_SETMARQUEE, 1,0);... (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760842(v=vs.85).aspx) ...

Comment: @ David Heffernan No. I don't know if it's just my failure or if it's the wrong solution... You want me to call CreateWindowEx() and not to use GetWindowLongPtr() etc, right?

Comment: Well, you must not remove `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE` which is what your code currently does.

Comment: Hmm, now i have my CreateWindowEx() declaration and your way to change the style of the progress bar. The fact that the bar appears tells me that i don't remove WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE anymore... But the progress bar still doesn't move...  

SendMessage(hwndPB,(UINT) PBM_SETMARQUEE,(WPARAM) 1,(LPARAM)NULL) returns false.

Comment: I don't know. That should work. But since I can't see all of your code I'm now out of ideas. When you get it working you probably want to include the PBS_SMOOTH style, but that's something else to be done after you solve your current problem.

Comment: @sambob I think I've cracked it now!

Comment: @sambob Do you have any feedback? Is this the answer?

Comment: @ David. Sorry, was not able to code anything the last two days. I don't know that much about pragma statements or precompiled header files but i guess those commands only work in visual studio? I'm working with the CodeBlocks IDE and the GNU GCC compiler. 
So it isn't working for me at the moment, but i still don't know if it's my bad or if the command just doesn't work in for my configuration.

Comment: Thank you David, I was getting very frustrated.  The pragma hint fixed my issue.