# change color in progress bar win 32

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to change the color of background and bar in a win 32 progress bar in the following way :

```
HWND hwndPB =CreateWindowEx(0, PROGRESS_CLASS, NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |PBS_SMOOTHREVERSE | PBS_MARQUEE ,
    20, 50, 275, 20,
    hwndDlg, NULL,NULL , NULL);

SetWindowLongPtr(hwndDlg,GWLP_USERDATA,reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(hwndPB));
SendMessage(hwndPB,(UINT)PBM_SETBKCOLOR,0,RGB(200,200,200));
SendMessage(hwndPB,(UINT) PBM_SETBARCOLOR,0,(LPARAM)RGB(100,100,100));
SendMessage(hwndPB,(UINT) PBM_SETMARQUEE,(WPARAM) TRUE,(LPARAM)50 );
```

I guess this is not working because of the visual themes being enabled. Can anybody suggest me a way to get it done or disable the visual styles. I am using VS 2008. Also, its a non mfc application.

Comment: Disabling Visual Styles is a user choice, so you shouldn't do that. --- I *guess* it should be easy to draw the progress bar yourself, if it's just a simple one.

Comment: @peterchen : Thank u . Is there a way to customize the progress bar without repainting/drawing it by using win 32 commands.

Comment: @peterchen You contradict yourself. One the one hand you advise that the user controls the appearance of this control. And then you suggest that grv paints the control and so take the control out of the hands of the user.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I wouldn't advise to turn off visual styles for the entire system (clearly users land), nor for the entire application just because one or two controls that should look non-differently. The impact on user experience of a single custom drawn control is much less. A progress bar's color can act as a visual cue to additional information that is available otherwise, just not as neatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable themes for an individual control by calling [`SetWindowTheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827.aspx). For your progress bar, disable the theming like this:

```
SetWindowTheme(hwndPB, "", "");
```

Once you have disabled the theming, you'll be able to control the colors.

Comment: It looks like i might be missing something here and getting the following compilation error : error C3861: 'SetWindowTheme': identifier not found .. Can you please throw some light.

Comment: Read the MSDN documentation link I provided. You need to include `Uxtheme.h` and pass `UxTheme.lib` to the linker. These MSDN documentation topics all follow the same template. Look at the bottom of the topic for the requirements. Be aware that you'll need to target a minimum version of XP to be able to use the theme API.

Comment: @grv Are you hoping for more than this? I think it does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. I have been trying it , but am entangled in some other errors in the application. Once i am able to sort it out, I hope i should be abke to get the results. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Hello , after trying the solution suggested i am stuck with the following: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537289/rc2247-cannot-open-rc-file   Any thoughts about where i might have gone wrong.

Comment: Also the progress bar solution mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681467/pbs-marquee-progressbar-winapi/16542215#16542215  has lots of flickering in the bar. Can you please tell me if i am missing anything!! Thanks

Comment: I'd like to finish this question first. Are you going to keep asking different questions in comments, until your entire program is complete?

Comment: Thanks lot David. I have been able to achieve the solution. Thanks again for your expertise and direction.