# RC2247 : Cannot open Rc file : Resource explorer cannot load resource ; Load failed

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker-errors

I have a win 32 project I'm working on and the resource file were working fine till yesterday. Now when I try to open the resource file to edit, it crashes and gives me the following error:

```
 C://program files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v6.0A/include/prsht.h(0)
 error RC2247: Symbol name too long
```

Can anybody tell me where I might be going wrong or where to look into. The rc file is  a very simple dialog box with a static text and a progress bar.

Comment: Compare the broken resource file with the last working version of the resouce file and try to narrow down what additions lead to the problem.

Comment: ... and I just stumbled upon this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcprerelease/thread/4a648d6a-ea81-44d3-89c2-57fa5caa6fd6 by doing a google search with following search term: "RC2247" :-)

Comment: @MichaelWalz : The solution provided in the link doesnot get rid of the error.

Comment: Replace the series of #include lines in your .rc file..........

Comment: Can you show the include portion of the .rc file.

Comment: I recreated the resources to eradicate the errors. Also , i could get rid of the errors by changing the order in which i was including my project header files.

Answer (score 11):

I had the error as well. The approach mentioned in the [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/{...} Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a648d6a-ea81-44d3-89c2-57fa5caa6fd6/vs2008-resource-view-crashes-with-rc2247-when-prshth-included-as-a-resource-include) (in a comment from Michael Walz) should work. Here's what you have to do:

Find the part where the windows headers are included. This might be the `"windows.h"` include, or if you use MFC, it is the `<afxres.h>` include. Add the "prsht.h" header after your `"windows.h"` include (this did the trick for me). Also surround it with the two lines containing APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS, to hide the lines from the resource editor. It should look like this:

```
#define APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS
#include "windows.h"
#include "prsht.h"
#undef APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS
```

Comment: This is a lifesaver, but I am dubious about using "..." instead of <...> for system includes like this. I have many projects where doing that would result in the wrong header being included.

Answer (score -1):

1.download a tool named `ResEdit`,if you can't find this tool,can email to me.
 juxuan_xatu@126.com

2.open the *.rc file.

3.click everyone diadlag, save it.

4.then use vc2008 to open it again.