# error RC2247: Symbol name too long (winnt.h)

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-studio-2017

I'm getting an RC2247 error (Symbol name too long) when attempting to display the dialogs in a Win32 app. The error is occurring in this file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\um\winnt.h
```

This worked fine under VS2015. The error started when I upgraded to VS2017.

I have seen the following posts, they don't appear to be relevant because they pertain to `prsht.h`:

[RC2247 : Cannot open Rc file : Resource explorer cannot load resource ; Load failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537289/rc2247-cannot-open-rc-file-resource-explorer-cannot-load-resource-load-fai)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcprerelease/thread/4a648d6a-ea81-44d3-89c2-57fa5caa6fd6

The error disappears if I comment out the entire `resource.rc` file. The error occurs if the RC contains the single line:

```
#include <winnt.h>
```

When I click on "Edit code"", nothing happens.

I am grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: use `#include <winres.h>` in *.rc* file. not include `winnt.h` or `windows.h`. the `winres.h` is special design for *RC* compiler (include internal several *rh* files - inluding *winnt.rh*, *winuser.rh*, etc), when `winnt.h` is for *CL* and not design for *RC*

Comment: @RbMm It works! Awesome. Thanks very much. I also had to get rid of `winuser.h`. So why has this been working OK for twenty years and all of a sudden it fails? That's progress I guess.

Comment: again - you not need include *winuser.h* - this file for *c/c++* compiler - you need include *winuser.rh* instead for *rc*. but when you include *winres.h* - you auto include *winuser.h* , *winnt.rh*, *commctrl.rh* etc.

Comment: *winuser.h* for *RC* - this is like *windows.h* for *CL*. in c/c++ include *windows.h* and to *rc* file include *winres.h* (but never *windows.h*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We must not include *windows.h* or *winnt.h* to *.rc* file - this headers - for are for c/c++ compilers and not designed for *RC* (resource compiler which process *.rc* file). as result if we include such files we may get errors.

We need include `#include <winres.h>` to *.rc* files. this file specially designed for the *RC* compiler. Internally it included:

```
#include <winuser.rh>
#include <commctrl.rh>
#include <dde.rh>
#include <winnt.rh>
#include <dlgs.h>
#include <winver.h>
```

and define some macros.

All standard windows definitions, which we need/use in *rc* file - exist in *winres.h* (and it subincludes). From another side in it no extra symbols/definitions wich exist in *windows.h* - it's not needed for *rc*  and some time can cause errors.

So simply `#include <winres.h>` at the beginning of resource files and all will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this complaint rc2247 when trying to edit the rc file in a project compiled in vs2010. This had been upgraded from vs2050. I found that if I chose to open the .sin file via 'version selector' instead of going straight to vs2010, then it still opens in vs2010 but there is no problem in editing the rc. I don't pretend to understand !
CalendarMan