# indeterminate progress bar?

Tags: c++, mfc, progress-bar

How make infinite indeterminate progress bar in MFC Application?

There is my source but its not infinite as I want.

```
WaitProcessDlg::WaitProcessDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(WaitProcessDlg::IDD, pParent)
{

}

void WaitProcessDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_PROGRESS1, m_Progress);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(WaitProcessDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL WaitProcessDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    str = pApp->GetProfileString(_T("Process"), _T("Process"));
    if(tempHWND = ::FindWindow(NULL, str)){
        EndDialog( 0 );
    }else{
        CMFCRibbonProgressBar* pProgressBar = new CMFCRibbonProgressBar(IDC_PROGRESS1, pProgressBar);

        pProgressBar->SetInfiniteMode(m_bInfiniteProgressMode);
        pProgressBar->SetRange(0, 200);
        pProgressBar->SetPos(200, true);

        m_Progress.SetInfiniteMode(m_bInfiniteProgressMode);
        m_Progress.SetRange(0, 100);
        SetTimer(IDC_PROGRESS1, 0, NULL);
    }

    return TRUE;

}
void WaitProcessDlg::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{

    while (m_Progress.GetPos() != 100){
        if (tempHWND = ::FindWindow(NULL, str)){
            EndDialog(0);
            KillTimer(IDC_PROGRESS1);
        }
            m_Progress.OffsetPos(1);
    }
    while (m_Progress.GetPos() != 0){
        if (tempHWND = ::FindWindow(NULL, str)){
            EndDialog(0);
            KillTimer(IDC_PROGRESS1);
        }
            m_Progress.OffsetPos(-1);
    }
  CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

I need some example or what on how to create a Indeterminate progress bars on MFC like so:
[Progress bar](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC121865.png)

Comment: Hmm .. "but its not infinite as I want"? So what is it instead? ..A quick google search suggests you may need to SetPos to "0", by the way.

Comment: not at all. there is no condition to do that. Because my progress bar at now as u se increases until 200 and then decreases until 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create an indeterminate progress bar (called a Marquee), you need to set the `Marquee` property of the progress bar to `True` in your dialog editor.

[image: Set Marquee to True]

Then, in your `InitDialog` method, you need to call the `SetMarquee` method on the progress bar:

```
BOOL CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    m_Progress.SetMarquee(TRUE, 1); // Start the marquee

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Marquee result]

Comment: @slashp Where are you stuck? What have you tried? It would help if you post some code or tell us some details.

Comment: Looks like I needed to #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"") in my stdafx.h as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681467/pbs-marquee-progressbar-winapi ....thanks for lookin out though!